# Linq to sql stored procedure call wrong result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I'm using Linq to Sql in my project to call stored procedures. It's a get stored procedure which return few rows

```
`Return db.ProcName(param1, param2, ......,paramN).ToList`
```

It calls the stored procedure correctly with correct parameters. I can see that by running the SQL profiler. When I run the stored procedure in management studio I get right result. If the run the sql statements logged in profile log, I get the right results.

Problem is when Linq receives the data, basically the results returned by `ToList` are not same as what was returned by the database. I do remember something about `NULL` values or when there is no `primary key` Linq does funny things, but I'm not sure what exactly it is.

Can someone point out what's going on here? Table 1 is the results returned by stored proc when executed in management studio and table 2 is the result returned when Linq to Sql code executes

Table 1:

```
OrgRef OrgCode DisplayName StockTakeId StockTakeName   StockPositionDate   StockTakeOrganisationReturnId   SubmittedBy ReturnStatus    IsEditable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9391    K81060  Name        2           Type2           NULL                NULL                            NULL            NULL        1
9391    K81060  Name        1           Type1           2014-05-20          311                             Sachin Kalra    Saved       1
9391    K81060  Name        1           Type1           2014-10-08          312                             Sachin Kalra    Saved       1
```

Table 2:

```
OrgRef OrgCode DisplayName StockTakeId StockTakeName   StockPositionDate   StockTakeOrganisationReturnId   SubmittedBy ReturnStatus    IsEditable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9391    K81060  Name        2           Type2           NULL                NULL                            NULL            NULL        1
9391    K81060  Name        1           Type1           2014-05-20          311                             Sachin Kalra    Saved       1
9391    K81060  Name        1           Type1           NULL                NULL                                Sachin Kalra    Saved       1
```

In table 1 as you can see second and third row have a value for column 6(StockPositionDate) and column 7 (StockTakeOrganisationReturnId) but in table 2 these values become NULL.

Anyone have any idea why it's happening, even though the stored proc is called with right parameters.

Comment: I'm not still sure what it was, I was testing it wrong or just rebuilding did something. I've marked the answer to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try rebuilding the DBML file, it may be that the model has changed and LINQ is getting confused trying to put new data into an old model.

Comment: Maybe not the whole thing. Usually when I've had issues with EF with procs, I'll just delete the function import, the custom result type, and the stored proc, then re-add the proc to get those back, which usually helps - so I don't have to rebuild the whole thing.